# Calcular a soma de um intervalo de números informados pelo usuário

Tags: python

> Ler 15 números digitados pelo usuário e calcule a média dos valores entre as posições x e y (inclusive).

Eu comecei tentando fazer...

```
numeros = []
for i in range (1, 16):
    numeros.append(int(input(f"Digite o {i} Número: ")))

x = int(input("Entre com o limite Superior 'x':"))
y = int(input("Entre com o limite Inferior 'y':"))

somatorio = 0
for s in range(x, y+1):
    somatorio = somatorio + numeros[s]
print(f"O somatório é: {somatorio}")
```

Mas não consigo fazer nem meu somatório fazer o cálculo certo.
Eu sei que são muitas coisas bem básicas de iniciante, mas se puderem ajudar eu agradeço desde já!

Comment: Daniel, o site possui suporte a sintaxe de códigos nas perguntas, basta utilizar o botão `{}` do editor. Poderia [edit] e corrigir isso postando o código? Já adianto que você está definindo `somatorio` como 0 dentro do laço e que o seu limite superior virou o inferior e vice-versa.

Comment: Favor, não postar o [código como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/75104). Faça o [tour] e edite a pergunta.

Answer (score 4):

1. Ao usar `somatorio = 0` dentro da estrutura de repetição `for`, o seu `somatorio` sempre será reiniciado como `0` antes de somar o próximo número. Remova essa inicialização de dentro da estrutura de repetição pois ela não deve repetir, e sim ser executada uma vez só, antes de começar o calculo:

   ```
   somatorio = 0
   for s in range(....):
   ```
2. a função `range()` funciona da seguinte forma: Se você passar 2 parâmetros, o primeiro parâmetro é o número inicial, e o segundo é o número final. Da forma que você fez, você está solicitando que o usuário digite o limite superior e armazenando na variável `x`, porém na hora de usar o `range(x, y)` colocou o `x` como primeiro parâmetro! Está invertido. Para corrigir você deve trocar em um dos dois pontos:

   - Armazenar o limite **inferior** em `x` ao invés do **superior**:

     ```
      x = int(input("Entre com o limite inferior 'x':"))
     ```
   - Ou então inverter a chamada da função range:

     ```
      for s in range(y, x):
     ```
3. Da mesma forma que você fez no `range(1, 16)` para gerar 15 números, é preciso colocar `+1` no limite superior ao usar a função `range()`, pois ela termina um passo antes de alcançar o número passado. Então ficaria: `range(x, y+1)` (ou `range(y, x+1)` se você inverteu a ordem como sugerido no ítem acima)
4. Python é muito mais simples e didático do que C, é possível escrever esse mesmo código de forma muito mais intuitiva e eficiente. No exemplo abaixo, o mesmo código usa somente duas linhas, mas continua legível. Vou deixar aqui a título de estudo e futura referência:

   ```
   # Já cria a lista diretamente com os números digitados:
   numeros = [int(input(f"Digite o {i} número:")) for i in range(1, 16)]
   # Já soma direto:
   somatorio = sum(
       numeros[int(input('Limite inferior:')):int(input('Limite superior'))+1])
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Opa,
Deixa eu ver se consigo te ajudar. 
Se você atribuiu o limite superior à variável x e o limite inferior à variável y, ao fazer o seu laço o range está indo do limite superior (x) para o inferior(y), seria interessante inverter a ordem.
Agora, em relação ao valor do somatório, você está atribuindo 0 para a variável em cada iteração do laço, então você está sobrescrevendo o valor do somatório toda vez que aquele pedaço do codigo roda. Se você declarar o somatório = 0 fora do laço, provavelmente tera o resultado esperado.

Abs,

Comment: Resolvido! Obrigado a todos! Aprendi bastante em apenas 1 questão